# OrderBy specific elements in List

Tags: asp.net, linq, list

My scenario is: I have a class called `MenuBO` using linq, it has a function called `SelectAll()` that returns a list of the object `menu` to use as a `DataSource` for a `DropDownList`. Before returning it I need to insert in the list a new item to serve as a default value for the `DropDownList`

Here's what I tried so far:

```
public List<menu> SelectAll()
{
    using (var db = new SeloQual_AdminEntities(conn))
    {
        menu vmenu = new menu();
        vmenu.cod_menu = 0;
        vmenu.cod_menu_pai = null;
        vmenu.des_menu = "Select...";
        var query = from p in db.menu orderby p.des_menu select p;
        var test = query.ToList();
        test.Add(vmenu);
        return test.OrderBy(x => x.cod_menu).ToList();
    }
}
```

The `OrderBy(x => x.cod_menu)` does it job, the `vmenu` item appears on top like I want, but I need that the other items to be ordered by `des_menu`. I tried something like

```
return teste.OrderBy(x => x.cod_menu).ThenBy(y => y.des_menu).ToList();
```

But didn't work of course, so I some need help to order only the elements after the first one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you really want is the following code:

```
menu vmenu = new menu();
vmenu.cod_menu = 0;
vmenu.cod_menu_pai = null;
vmenu.des_menu = "Select...";
var query = from p in db.menu orderby p.des_menu select p;

List<menu> result = new List<menu>();
result.Add(vmenu);
result.AddRange(query);
return result;
```

This solves your problem elegantly by simply adding the default menu item first and adding the already sorted menu items afterwards in the order defined in the query.

Comment: Another possible way, if you wanted to avoid imperatively building up the list: `return new[] { vmenu }.Concat(query).ToList();`

Comment: @cdhowie: I find this highly unreadable and avoid it if possible.

Comment: Not saying it's the way the OP should go, just pointing it out as an alternative.

Comment: Thanks, but since there isn't going to be a lot of content in the list I will go for the solution of Raphaël Althaus, but thanks anyway

Comment: But yours is the best answer so I will chose it

Answer (score 1):

you could just use [Insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sey5k5z4%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) instead of Add

```
var vmenu = new menu{
    cod_menu = 0,
    des_menu="Select..."
    };
List<menu>res = db.menu.OrderBy(p => p.des_menu).ToList();
res.Insert(0,vmenu);
return res;
```

Comment: A valid technique, but introduces an unnecessary performance issue; if the result set is rather large, this will put the results into the list and then shift all of the list elements down by one.  (Well, it will do this regardless, but it may wind up being a bottleneck if the result set is large.)

Comment: Thanks, it worked, thought that using `Insert` would replace the position 0 of the list instead of moving it up, thanks!

Comment: @cdhowie I agree (not sure this will be the performance bottleneck, but yes, Daniel's answer is better).

Comment: Since there's not much items I don't think it will be a problem